# How to extend a list by overwriting the common values

Tags: python

```
list1=[{"status":1, "s_count":100}, {"status":2, "s_count":20}]
list2=[{"status":1, "s_count":0}, {"status":3, "s_count":30}]
```

`list1.extend(list2)` gives

```
[{"status":1, "s_count":100}, {"status":2, "s_count":20}, {"status":1, 
    "s_count":0}, {"status":3, "s_count":30}]
```

what I want is,

```
[{"status":1, "s_count":0}, {"status":2, "s_count":20}, {"status":3, "s_count":30}]
```

Comment: How is this related to Django? This is just common list manipulating in Python. You should also post what you have tried so far.

Comment: @OptimusCrime I have written the desired output and the output that I am getting.

Comment: Instead of a list `[{"status": x, "count": y}, ...]` you should really just use a dict (or `OrderedDict` if needed, or `Counter`) `{x: y, ...}`. This would be much easier to work with, including in this case.

Answer (score 1):

1) Consider using a dictionary instead of a list.

2) If you insist on using a list:

```
helper = []
for i in range(0,len(list1)):
  for item in list2:
     if item['status'] == list1[i]['status']:
         list1[i]['s_count'] = item['s_count']
         helper.add(item)
for item in helper:
    list2.remove(item)
list1.extend(list2)
```

This is inefficient, so try to do 1 if possible.